# Why is a trigger('click') being returned?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JS and trying to understand basic concepts. I want to learn object oriented JS, but I am coming to my difficulty. I am trying to understand the usage of the return statement. I was just going through the code in dropdown.js and came across the following line:

```
return $this.trigger('click')
```

Now I am used to seeing:

```
return true 

return false
```

And even:

```
return (1 + 1) > 10 ;
```

I know the usage of these return statements. My general overview of the return statement is it is used for returning a value that you would like to use in another place.

I still can not understand why this statement is being used:

```
return $this.trigger('click');
```

This line can also be found on [line 75](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/dropdown.js#L75) on git.

Thank you.

Alex-z.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that this is part of the `Dropdown.prototype.keydown` method, so we are detecting which key was pressed at the line you are referring to

```
if ((!isActive && e.which != 27) || (isActive && e.which == 27)) {
  if (e.which == 27) $parent.find(toggle).trigger('focus')
  return $this.trigger('click')
}
```

Char code 27 is the escape key. So if the user hit the escape key, trigger the on click event for this element (dropdown) and return the jQuery object (because of jQuery chaining).

Comment: @Kjprince , Oh , so chaning is the only purpose ?

Comment: Yeah, jQuery returns "itself" so that any method that calls it can keep interacting with the same object so you can do something like `$this.trigger('click').addClass('clicked').css('width', '100%')` for example.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that. `trigger` function returns `this` object. 
So the whole thing called would be the same as.

```
var that = $this.trigger('click')
return that;
```

But as long as you need to trigger some event, f.e. the keydown event was fired, you trigger the needed event and in the same line return that object.

Answer (score 0):

the **this** in **return $this** has no meaning until it enters a context. When it is returned, the function it returned to is told to do something with a **this** in its own context

Answer (score 0):

The documentation at https://api.jquery.com/trigger/ says that .trigger returns jQuery object.

It does that so that you can use it in function chaining. Which means you can do:
 $this.trigger('click').someOtherJqueryFunction();

If you had not return jQuery object you couldn't have done that.

For simple example let's say you've a object call Person that has properties as Home, Dog

Simple example not involving jQuery.
Let's say there is a function to set the home and dog but that function returns person object:

```
function setHomeName(name){
    homeName = name;
    return this; // return person
}

function setDogName(name){
    dogName = name;
    return this; // return person
}
```

Now you can do person.setHomeName('home name').setDogName('dog name');

Which is equivalent to person.setHomeName('home name'); person.setDogName('dog name').

As person.setHomeName() is returning reference to person object itself we can chain the function together and write all in one lines. This chain as you can see from jQuery example can be pretty long.

Comment: How can the return value of this event handler be used in a meaningful way?  I can understand the benefit of returning false from an event handler, but return a jquery object?

Comment: Right, but it's an event handler.  Returning false would cancel the event.  Returning a jquery object does what?